# Hide Contents of Navigation Drawer - com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.1.6@aar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am using a Navigation drawer in my Main screen and use the third party library **com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.1.6@aar**, to build my Material Drawer. My requirement is that I want to hide some menu items based on a condition. Is there a way to achieve it? This is how I create my drawer.

```
private Drawer result = null;
 AccountHeader headerResult;

final PrimaryDrawerItem home = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Home").withIdentifier(1).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_home);
        final PrimaryDrawerItem profile = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Profile").withIdentifier(2).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_account);
        final PrimaryDrawerItem gallery = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Gallery").withIdentifier(3).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_perm_media_black_24dp);
        final PrimaryDrawerItem recognition = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Recognition").withIdentifier(4).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_face);
        final PrimaryDrawerItem maps = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Maps").withIdentifier(5).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_place_black_24dp);
        final PrimaryDrawerItem tagAndLocate = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Tag & Locate").withIdentifier(6).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_remove_red_eye_black_24dp);
        final PrimaryDrawerItem gamesAndPuzzle = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Games & Puzzles").withIdentifier(7).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_casino_black_24dp);
        final PrimaryDrawerItem backup = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Backup").withIdentifier(8).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_save);
        final PrimaryDrawerItem logout = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Logout").withIdentifier(9).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_sign_out);

headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.header)
                .withSelectionListEnabledForSingleProfile(false)
                .addProfiles(userProfile)
                .withOnAccountHeaderListener(new AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onProfileChanged(View view, IProfile profile, boolean currentProfile) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .build();

            result = new DrawerBuilder()
                    .withActivity(this)
                    .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
                    .withToolbar(toolbar)
                    .withDisplayBelowStatusBar(false)
                    .withTranslucentStatusBar(true)
                    .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                    .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
                    .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
                    .addDrawerItems(home)
                    .addDrawerItems(profile)
                    .addDrawerItems(gallery)
                    .addDrawerItems(recognition)
                    .addDrawerItems(maps)
                    .addDrawerItems(tagAndLocate)
                    .addDrawerItems(gamesAndPuzzle)
                    .addDrawerItems(backup)
                    .addDrawerItems(new DividerDrawerItem())
                    .addDrawerItems(logout)
                    .buildForFragment();

        resultStandard.setOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {

                    int drawItemId = (int) drawerItem.getIdentifier();
                    Intent intent;
                    Fragment fragment;
                    switch (drawItemId) {

                        case 1:
                                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                                gaFragmentStack.add(home);
                                break;

                        case 2:
                            fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                            gaFragmentStack.add(profile);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            fragment = new GalleryFragment();
                            gaFragmentStack.add(gallery);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            fragment = new RecognitionFragment();
                            gaFragmentStack.add(recognition);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            fragment = new MapsFragment();
                            gaFragmentStack.add(maps);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            fragment = new TagLocateFragment();
                            gaFragmentStack.add(tagAndLocate);
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            fragment = new GamesPuzzlesFragment();
                            gaFragmentStack.add(gamesAndPuzzle);
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            fragment = new BackupFragment();
                            gaFragmentStack.add(backup);
                            break;
                        default:
                            fragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;
                    }
                    if (drawItemId == 9) {
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                        editor.clear();
                        editor.apply();
                        intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, SplashScreen.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.container_gaFragments, fragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

I just want to hide some Drawer item based on a condition. Is there a way to do that? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hide a particular item from the drawer. You can resolve this by removing all items (removeAllItems() and removeAllStickyFooterItems()) and adding them selectively again. Below is the example code for Kotlin where you can handle this with IF statement inside the slider.apply {...}

```
fun refreshMenuItems() {
    slider.apply {
        removeAllItems()
        removeAllStickyFooterItems()
    
        if (isLoggedUser == false) {
            addItems(
                PrimaryDrawerItem().apply {
                    nameText = "Login"
                    iconicsIcon = GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_verified_user
                    identifier = 70
                },
                DividerDrawerItem(),
                PrimaryDrawerItem().apply {
                    nameText = "Register"
                    iconicsIcon = GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_how_to_reg
                    identifier = 80
                }
            )
        } else {
            addItems(
                PrimaryDrawerItem().apply {
                    nameText = "My profile"
                    iconicsIcon = GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_verified_user
                    identifier = 70
                },
                DividerDrawerItem(),
                PrimaryDrawerItem().apply {
                    nameText = "My reservations"
                    iconicsIcon = GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_how_to_reg
                    identifier = 80
                }
            )
    
            addStickyDrawerItems(
                PrimaryDrawerItem().apply {
                    nameText = "Log out"
                    isSelectable = false
                    identifier = 100
                }
            )
        }
    }

}
```

For example, you can call this method from onResume() method

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    changeDrawerUserName()
    refreshMenuItems()
}
```